# teradata sql for ommitting space

Tags: sql, database, teradata

I am working on a table and want to count number of instances of a column (student name) where it does not have any space.
Like only 'SAM' or "STAN'.
My query is:

```
select studentName
from loadbise.student
where studentName <>'% %'
and studentName is not null;
```

It returns column with spaces. What am I missing.
I am working on old version of teradata (6.0) which does not support replace function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a 'not like' clause intead of 'not equal'. See below.

```
select studentName
from loadbise.student
where studentName not like '% %'
and studentName is not null;
```

see this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0a3cf/2) for an additional example. This query will likely be very inefficient over large sets of data, so it might be beneficial to insert an index on the studentName column if one does not already exist.

Comment: Teradata's optimizer will almost always ignore a secondary index when using the NOT LIKE predicate. Another option would be to use the `POSITION(' ' IN StudentName) = 0` in your WHERE clause. This too will not likely use an index and result in a full table scan.